# Apache Virtual Host configuration for PHP routes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, virtualhost

I am deploying on an Apache for the first time.

Here is my Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
               DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject.com/web/my-project/Client/app/

            ServerName myproject.com
            ServerAlias www.myproject.com

            ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/myproject.com/error.log

            Alias /error/ "/var/www/myproject.com/web/error/"
            Alias /api/ "/var/www/myproject.com/web/my-project/Server/"
            ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
            ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
            ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
            ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
            ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
            ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
            ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
            ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /api
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

My HTML and Javascript are served properly. But the API calls are responding with 404, saying '*The requested URL was not found on this server.*'

Why is it not finding 'countries' route from my route.php when 'my-project/api/countries' is requested?

**EDIT**:
I just checked my error log and it is showing 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration' several times.

Answer (score 0):

One of your rewrite rules needs correction. See correct directives below:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /api
 # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @starkeen, your comment was directed to me or William Greenly?
And I guess the problem is with the .vhost file, not .htaccess file.